# Ir para o fim da página

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, queria saber como faz para fazer quando a pessoa clica, irá para o fim da página. Se puderem me ensinar eu agradeço!! No caso era quando clicasse em algum destes textos, http://prntscr.com/by6y69

Comment: Para o fim mesmo? Ou para uma determinada secção?

Comment: Para uma secção que no caso é uma box http://prntscr.com/by742u

Comment: Está a usar jquery? Isso não faz com php, mas sim com javascript. Deve acrescentar/substituir as tags javascript e jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para fazer scroll até ao fim da página:

```js
$('#down').on('click', function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(document).height()
  }, 700);
});
```

```css
#div1 {
 height: 1000px;
 background-color: red;
}
#div2 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <button id="down">IR LÁ PARA BAIXO</button>
</div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Para fazer scroll até a um determinado elemento:

```js
var ele = $('#div2');
$('#down').on('click', function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: ele.offset().top
  }, 700);
});
```

```css
#div1 {
 height: 1000px;
 background-color: red;
}
#div2 {
  height: 800px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <button id="down">IR PARA DIV2</button>
</div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

NOTE que num projeto real em príncipio escusa de colocar a `height` nas divs, pois a altura destas devem ser definidas pelo seu conteúdo

Comment: Aonde eu colocaria este código?: var ele = $('#div2');
$('#down').on('click', function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: ele.offset().top
  }, 700);
});

Comment: Dentro do evento que quer delegar para isso, no meu caso foi dentro do click do botão @Vinicius. Ou seja, no click no botão vai acontecer isso. Pode só ajustar o elemento a clicar, no meu caso foi no elemento cujo id é `down`

Comment: Queria colocar no caso dentro deste código que é como descrito no print: http://prntscr.com/by74y8 (Código: <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getContentPage('topevent');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" style=" font-size: 10pt"></span> Ranking </a></li>)

Comment: Você consegue mudar o código HTML @Vinicius? Se sim, faça `<a href="#" id="down">...`, depois na linha a seguir a `}, 700);` coloque um `return false;`

Comment: Miguel tenho que te dizer, não manjo muito de PHP ou HTML então isto complica para mim, só não estou entendendo aonde adiciona este primeiro código, pois queria que quando clicasse no texto ranking iria para  o final da página (Parece ser mais fácil) só isto, se voce puder me explicar de uma forma mais fácil que voce puder acho que eu entendo rs. Espero que não entenda mal.

Comment: Não claro que não @Vinicius. `<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getContentPage('topevent');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" style=" font-size: 10pt"></span> Ranking </a>` . Deve ficar: `<a href="#" id="down"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" style=" font-size: 10pt"></span> Ranking </a>` e depois na linha a seguir a `}, 700);` na parte js que eu coloquei, escreva `return false;` . Este codigo deve ser colocado dentro das tag `<script>` e depois de importar o jquery: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: O 2 código é no css?

Comment: @Vinicius, aqui está o segundo exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/0dtsg39y/ . E aqui está o primeiro: https://jsfiddle.net/0dtsg39y/1/

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43085/discussion-between-vinicius-and-miguel).